# Translating If/Else && RegEx - Ruby to Python

Tags: python, regex

I wrote a program in Ruby that takes the user's weight/height as input. I am stuck converting it to Python. Here is my Ruby code, which works fine:

```
print "How tall are you?"
height = gets.chomp()
if height.include? "centimeters"
     #truncates everything but numbers and changes the user's input to an integer
    height = height.gsub(/[^0-9]/,"").to_i / 2.54
else
    height = height
end

print "How much do you weigh?"
weight = gets.chomp()
if weight.include? "kilograms"
    weight = weight.gsub(/[^0-9]/,"").to_i * 2.2 
else
    weight = weight 
end

puts "So, you're #{height} inches tall and #{weight} pounds heavy."
```

Does anyone have any hints or pointers on how I can translate this? Here's my Python code:

```
print "How tall are you?",
height = raw_input()
if height.find("centimeters" or "cm")
    height = int(height)  / 2.54
else
    height = height

print "How much do you weight?",
weight = raw_input()
if weight.find("kilograms" or "kg")
    weight = int(height) * 2.2
else
    weight = weight

print "So, you're %r inches tall and %r pounds heavy." %(height, weight)
```

It's not running. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
MacBook-Air:Python bdeely$ python ex11.py
How old are you? 23
How tall are you? 190cm
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex11.py", line 10, in <module>
    height = int(height) / 2.54
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '190cm'
```

Comment: `if height.find("centimeters" or "cm")` — this is like `if height.include? ("centimeters" || "cm")`. Python is good, but it’s not magic; try `"centimeters" in height or "cm" in height`. Same for the kilos. Then, you could use the same regular expression — look at the re module.

Comment: I'm not sure what `height = height` and `weight = weight` do in Ruby, but here in Python, you might as well leave them out

Comment: The number of formatting placeholders also doesn’t match up with the `(age, height, weight)` you’re passing. Anyways, adding the error that you’re trying to fix this time would be really helpful…

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.

I've since updated my code and added the error that happens.

Answer (score 1):

You've got other problems, but the first problem you'll encounter is that `if` and `else` statements require colons at the end of the line to introduce a block.

Answer (score 1):

This line won't do what you think it does:

```
if height.find("centimeters" or "cm")
```

Apart from the missing `:` (presumably that's a typo), the code won't work for two reasons:

- `str.find()` returns `-1` if nothing is found, `0` if the searched-for string is found at the start. `0` is considered `False` in a boolean context and you should instead test for `> -1`.
- You are not testing for either `'centimeters' or 'cm'`. You are only testing for `'centimeters'`. The `or` expression is evaluated first, and short-circuits to return the first `True`-ish value, the first non-empty string, so `'centimeters'` in this case.

You should *instead* test for the presence of strings using `in`:

```
if 'centimeters' in height or 'cm' in height:
```

Demo:

```
>>> height = '184cm'
>>> height.find("centimeters" or "cm")
-1
>>> 'centimeters' in height or 'cm' in height
True
>>> height = '184 centimeters'
>>> height.find("centimeters" or "cm")
4
>>> 'centimeters' in height or 'cm' in height
True
>>> height = 'Only fools and horses'
>>> height.find("centimeters" or "cm")
-1
>>> 'centimeters' in height or 'cm' in height
False
```

Your next problem is that `int()` won't take kindly to extra text in your input text. You already determined that `'centimeter'` is present, and that is what throws the exception.

You could use a regular expression, like the Ruby code:

```
import re

height = int(re.search('(\d+)', height).group(1)) / 2.54
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> height = '184cm'
>>> int(re.search('(\d+)', height).group(1)) / 2.54
72.44094488188976
>>> height = '184 centimeters'
>>> int(re.search('(\d+)', height).group(1)) / 2.54
72.44094488188976
```